# Template Pattern UML

Tags: java, uml

**Question:** By using the strategy pattern we can use object composition for different kinds of aliens with different recovery behaviors (ie noRecovery, linearRecovery, fractionalRecovery as a field in alien). if we choose to use the template pattern, we use inheritance to create different concrete alien classes. sketch the high level uml class names only

**Problem:** Im having trying the figure out how to map this out I know that my *template method is Recover*, my *primitive operations are noRecovery, linearRecovery, and fractionalRecovery and my calculateRecovery*, and my *concrete operation is CalculateRecovery*.

This is the UML i came up with:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Have you tried doing a search for the Template Pattern.  There are plenty of sites and books that explain these patterns and most if not all will have some sort of UML diagram.

Answer (score 0):

The [template method pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/template-method) uses specialization, so your diagram should show inheritance ([plain arrow with hollow triangular arrow head](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#/media/File%3AUml_classes_en.svg) - dashed arrow that you use mean dependency).

The template method pattern would use a general operation (method in Java) inherited from `Alien`, but that uses some auxiliary operations that can be defined/redefined (overridden in Java) in the subclasses.  But since you are supposed to show only the class name without details, you wouldn't show these details.

However, if the strategies would be called `LinearRecovery`,  `fractionalRecovery`, the composition would read out as `Alien` having a `LinearRecovery`, `Alien` having a `xyzRecovery`.  Using a template method instead of the strategy would then probably  name the different variants of aliens in the inheritance hierarchy `AlienWithLinearRecovery` or `AlienLinearRecorey` or something like that that shows that it's an alien with a specific behavior,  and not just `LinearRecovery`, as different kind of objects could also use  the same strategy (in other words, the name of the strategy is not sufficient to clarify that it's an alien).